# Trouble inserting into a sql table from a form

Tags: php, mysqli

The expect result is for the data that is submitted through a HTML form, and then the form action is this code below. Proccessing the code below I was expecting it to insert the data from the form into a SQL table called `customers`. However the data is not being inserted and there is no errors showing on the page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$uName = $_POST['uname'];
$password = sha1($_POST['upassword']);
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

echo $uName;
echo $password;

include("dbconn.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (username, password_hash, customer_foremane, customer_surname, date_of_birth, customer_address1, customer_address2, customer_postcode) VALUES ('$uName', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$dob', '$address1', '$address2', '$postcode')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

This is the form in which the data is from:

```
<div id = "reg_form">
    <form name="register" action="register_customer.php" method="post">
        <p id = "form_text"> Username: </p> <input name="uname" type="text" placeholder="Please enter a user name">
        <p id = "form_text"> Password: </p> <input name="upassword" type="password" placeholder="Please enter a password"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> First Name: </p> <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your first name"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> Last Name: </p> <input name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your last name"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> Date of Birth: </p> <input name="dob" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your date of birth"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> Address 1: </p> <input name="address1" type="text" placeholder="Please enter first line of address"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> Address 2: </p> <input name="address2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter second line of address"><br>
        <p id = "form_text"> Postcode: </p> <input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your postcode"><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the dbconn.php:

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],
    $config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    echo "Connected to the database";
?>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This code seems to have no problems for me. Can you post also the form and dbconn.php? Also please not that your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: There is the form and dbconn.php

Comment: There is no conditional at dbconn to verify a successful connection.  You need to implement prepared statements with placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use MySqli **Prepared Statements** for Inserting the query to make it more secure like below:

```
// prepare and bind Customers Query
$queryCustomers = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customers(username, password_hash, customer_foremane, customer_surname, date_of_birth, customer_address1, customer_address2, customer_postcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$queryCustomers->bind_param("ssssssss",$uName,$password,$fname,$lname,$dob,$address1,$address2,$postcode);

// execute Customers Query
$queryCustomers->execute();

// Close Connections
$queryCustomers->close();
```

To learn more, follow http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @your-common-sense Sir some person downvote if I not give exact answer   so given complete answer along with instructions to update.

Comment: In your answer you made two statements that are entirely wrong. It perfectly justifies such a vote. I removed these statements from your answer.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I will slowly learn to post better answer with better understanding.